# Question About Direct Limit Group Definition As Given In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This comes from page 243, section 3.3 of Hatcher.

Given a directed system of groups $G_{\alpha}$, he defines the *direct limit* group $\lim_{\rightarrow} G_\alpha$ as follows:

Define an equivalence relation on the set $\bigsqcup_{\alpha}G_\alpha$ by $a$~$b$ if $f_{\alpha \gamma}(a)=f_{\beta\gamma}(b)$ for some $\gamma$, where $a \in G_\alpha$ and $b \in G_\beta$.

I have verified that this is in fact an equivalence relation (transitivity takes a little thought), but he then remarks

> This equivalence relation could also be described as the equivalence relation generated by setting $a$~$f_{\alpha\beta}(a)$.
>
> I am having a difficult time proving this. I'm assuming he means $a$~$f_{\alpha\beta}(a)$ for all $\beta \geq \alpha$, is this correct? This second definition intuitively seems more like the notion of a limit than the first one. How does one show that this equivalence relation is the same as the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Hatcher does mean $a \sim f_{\alpha \beta}(a)$ for all $\beta \geq \alpha$. Now to show the two relations are the same, for convenience, we make distinct the symbols. If $a \sim b$ then there exists some $\gamma$ such that $\alpha, \beta \leq \gamma$ with $f_{\alpha \gamma}(a) = f_{\beta \gamma}(b)$. Further denote by $\hat\sim$ the relation generated by $a \hat\sim f_{\alpha \beta}(a)$ for all $\beta \geq \alpha$.

Now suppose $a \sim b$. By definition there exists some $\gamma$ meeting order requirements such that $f_{\alpha \gamma}(a)=f_{\beta \gamma}(b)$. Further we have $a  \hat\sim  f_{\alpha \gamma}(a)$ and $b \hat\sim f_{\beta \gamma}(b)$. Thus we rewrite $f_{\alpha \gamma}(a)$ and have $a \hat\sim f_{\beta \gamma}(b) \hat\sim b$. Thus $a \hat\sim b$.

For the other direction we make note that for each $\beta$ where it is well defined, the only element in $G_\beta$ that is related to $a$ under $\hat\sim$ is $f_{\alpha \beta}(a)$. Thus if $a_1,a_2 \in G_\alpha$ and $a_1 \hat\sim a_2$, as $a_1 \hat\sim f_{\alpha \alpha}(a_1)$ we deduce $a_2 = f_{\alpha \alpha}(a_1)=a_1$. So suppose $a \hat\sim b$ with $a \in G_\alpha, b \in G_\beta$. By our properties of the directed set we have the existence of $\gamma$ such that $\alpha,\beta \leq \gamma$. Then we have $f_{\alpha \gamma}(a) \hat\sim a \hat\sim b \hat\sim f_{\beta \gamma}(b)$. But $f_{\alpha \gamma}(a), f_{\beta \gamma}(b) \in G_\gamma$. Thus $f_{\alpha \gamma}(a)= f_{\beta \gamma}(b)$ so $a \sim b$ as desired.

So we can conclude that $a \sim b$ iff $a \hat\sim b$.

Comment: Thanks this is very clear and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f_{\alpha\beta}:G_\alpha\to G_\beta$ and $f_{\beta\gamma}:G_\beta\to G_\gamma$. We want to show that starting with the equivalence relation generated by the relations $a\sim f_{\alpha \gamma}(a) $ for all $\alpha\leq\gamma$ and all $a\in G_{\alpha}$, we can arrive at the relations in the original definiton and vice versa.

So suppose $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are appropriate such that for $f_{\alpha\gamma}(a)=f_{\beta\gamma}(b)$. We are allowed the relations $a\sim f_{\alpha \gamma}(a) $ and $b\sim f_{\beta \gamma}(b) $ and by reflexivity $f_{\alpha\gamma}(a)\sim f_{\beta\gamma}(b)$ since they are equal. By transitivity, conclude that $a\sim b$ and we can all be happy. You can do similar trickery using the equivalence relations to go the other way around. Since the generating sets of one equivalence relation can be used to generate the generating set of the other, they had better be the same relation.